# Horizontal scrolling with mouse wheel until the end of element, then switch to vertical

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

So I have a section of my page that once your vertically scroll to it, it acts as a blog slider that you can horizontally scroll through using your mouse wheel/trackpad. The end solution I want to achieve is to **enable vertical scrolling once the user has reached the end of the slider**. Here is the code I have:

```
<div id="post-wrapper">
  <p>Post 1</p>
  <p>Post 2</p>
  <p>Post 3</p>
  <p>Post 4</p>
  <p>Post 5</p>
  <p>Post 6</p>
</div>

<style>
 #post-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 100rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 #post-wrapper p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #c2d8db !important;
  color: white;
  padding: 10rem 15rem;
  margin: 2rem 1rem;
 }
</style>

<script>
const postScroll = document.getElementById("post-wrapper");
postScroll.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  postScroll.scrollBy({
    left: event.deltaY < 0 ? -70 : 70,
  });
        event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

I haven't tried much of anything else other than to try and replicate it using pure css, which is a nightmare. I know there are a lot of solutions similar to this but none of which show how resume the vertical scrolling once the end has been reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a variable `scrollingHorizontally` to keep track of whether we are currently scrolling horizontally or vertically, set it to true to indicate that we are scrolling horizontally & do the scroll logic.

Check this example...

```
const postScroll = document.getElementById("post-wrapper");
let scrollingHorizontally = true;

postScroll.addEventListener("wheel", (event) => {
  if (scrollingHorizontally) {
    postScroll.scrollBy({
      left: event.deltaY < 0 ? -70 : 70,
    });
    event.preventDefault();

    // check if the user has reached the end of the slider
    if (postScroll.scrollLeft >= postScroll.scrollWidth - postScroll.clientWidth) {
      scrollingHorizontally = false;
      postScroll.style.overflowY = "auto";
    }
  } else {
    // (scroll the page up/down)
    return true;
  }
});
```

Hope This Helps...

Answer (score 0):

The deltaY property can be positive ore negative. When it is positive it means the user is scrolling up and when it is negative the user is scrolling down.

```
 const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('main');

 scrollContainer.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
 });
```